# bsc get transactions by wallet address Web3.py

Tags: python, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3py

How can I track tokens transactions of a list of wallets in the bsc network?

I think about using websocket and filter function. I think it's possible to use the `topics` as a part of the filter parameters and reflect only the `Transfer` event to/from watched address, so that my app doesn't have to handle unnecessary data.

But I'm doing something wrong and don't know how to correctly give list of wallets (or at least only one wallet) as a parameter to my filter function. How to do that?

And I have problems with getting data from `Transfer` event as I don't know how to decode a `HexBytes` type. I saw web3.js functions for it but nothing with web3.py.

```
address_list = ['0x67fdE6D04a82689a59E5188f9B572CBeF53D4763', '...', '...']

web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('wss://bsc.getblock.io/mainnet/?api_key=your_api_key'))
web3_filter = web3.eth.filter({'topics': address_list}) 
while True:
    for event in web3_filter.get_new_entries():
        print(web3.toJSON(web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(event).logs))
```

Answer (score 6):

At last I found the solution. At first I wrote the same code using node.js, because web3.js makes it much simplier for me to understand how it actually works. It has better methods naming, better docs, etc

So back to web.py:

For getting `Transfer` event signature I used this code `transferEventSignature = web3.toHex(Web3.sha3(text='Transfer(address,address,uint256)'))`

For encoding/decoding you can use `eth_abi` library

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_abi import encode_abi, decode_abi
from hexbytes import HexBytes

encoded_wallet = (web3.toHex(encode_abi(['address'], [wallet])) # encoding

web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('wss://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/api-key/bsc/mainnet/ws'))
event_filter = web3.eth.filter({'topics': [transferEventSignature, None, encoded_wallet]}) # setting up a filter with correct parametrs
        while True:
            for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                decoded_address = decode_abi(['address'], HexBytes(event.topics[2])) # decoding wallet 
                value = decode_abi(['uint256'], HexBytes(event.data)) # decoding event.data

                tokenContractAddress = event.address

                contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(address=tokenContractAddress, abi=jsonAbi) # jsonAbi is standart erc-20 token abi 
                # I used simplified JSON abi that is only able to read decimals, name and symbol

                name = contractInstance.functions.name().call() 
                decimals = contractInstance.functions.decimals().call()
                symbol = contractInstance.functions.symbol().call()
                # getting any token information

                # doing some useful stuff
```

GetBlock.io worked for me, but would sometimes get out of sync with the network.
I have had better success with this service: https://moralis.io/

I hope somebody will find this usefull.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for you snippet but I search to do the same in web3js . Can you explain how did you does that please ? I don't find the "logic" behind the hood... thx

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code to track BEP20 token transactions:

```
def log_new(event_filter):
    for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
        handle_event(event)

def handle_event(event):
    receipt =  web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(event['transactionHash'])
    logs = contract.events.Transfer().processReceipt(receipt)

    args = logs[0]['args']

    print ("EVENT", event)
    hashstr = binascii.b2a_hex(event['transactionHash'])
    name = contract.functions.name().call() 
    decimals = contract.functions.decimals().call()
    symbol = contract.functions.symbol().call()

    item = {
        "from": args["from"],
        "to": args.to,
        "value": args.value,
        "blockNumber":event['blockNumber'],
        "transhash":  "0x" + hashstr.decode("ascii"),
        "timeStamp" : get_block_timestamp(event['blockNumber']),
        "tokenSymbol" : symbol, #"KAMPAY"
        "decimals" : decimals,
        "name" : name
    }
    print(item)


block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'latest','address':MYTOKENADDRESS})
while 1:
    log_new(block_filter)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bscscan** offers apis with free basic usage (5 req/sec)

So for having the list of transactions (there are different types of transactions including **normal**, **internal**, **bep-20** etc) you could use [this](https://bscscan.com/apis#accounts).

Sample usage would be [this](https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001004&startblock=1&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken).

Answer (score 0):

The `bscscan` api is not reliable. The problem is that the API is behind a cloudfare DDoS protection and a captcha is asked sometimes.  With Python code, there is no way to bypass this captcha check, unfortunately.